# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jsegcbha/mysqlclient/

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pip, macos-sierra

MacOS High Sierra

Python 3.6.3

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  celery:
    container_name: "cache_bot"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/celery/Dockerfile
    command: "celery -A cache_bot.app worker --loglevel=info"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/www
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache bash gcc libc-dev unixodbc-dev python3-dev

ADD ./src /www
ADD ./requirements.txt /home

WORKDIR /www

RUN pip install -r /home/requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
mysqlclient==1.3.12
...
```

When I run command 'docker-compose build' I get the error:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jsegcbha/mysqlclient/

ERROR: Service 'celery' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /home/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Full traceback:

Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.12 (from -r /home/requirements.txt (line 8))

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

/bin/sh: mysql_config: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/tmp/pip-install-jsegcbha/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in 
        metadata, options = get_config()

File "/tmp/pip-install-jsegcbha/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

File "/tmp/pip-install-jsegcbha/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config

raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

OSError: mysql_config not found

Actually, mysql_config is by path /usr/local/bin and this path is set up in $PATH

I've tried - RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools - in my Dockerfile. It did not help.

ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH in Dockerfile did not help as well.

Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `Dockerfile` the `python:3.6-alpine` is a reduced version of Python and the `mysqlclient` is looking for a development headers and libraries.

It is the official page [Pypi: mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

> Prerequisites:
>   You may need to install the Python and MySQL development headers and libraries...

**My solution:**

In my case I had the slim version and I changed to a Python 3 (3.7) and it works.

```
#FROM python:3-slim
FROM python:3
```

Comment: Good answer! Python and MySQL development headers and libraries is already in image python:3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue try this on the command line

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
sudo pip install pymysql
sudo pip install mysqlclient
```